# Deploy Angular website on GitHub products 404 error

Tags: git, angular, github

I have deployed a small static angular website on GitHub **[Link](https://yogyogi.github.io/app1/)**  but it has one problem. When i refresh any products page **[like this](https://yogyogi.github.io/app1/product/8)** then I get 404 error.

[image]

However when i navigate to any products pages from the home page then the product pages opens correctly.

This app's reprository link is - **[here](https://github.com/yogyogi/app1)**.

I am beginner in angular - please help me why it is doing so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using HTML pushState as location strategy due to which when you refresh from browser, the browser sends request of your routed page to Github. As Github is unaware of this internal routing by angular due to it shows 404 error.

There are couple of solutions:
1. If you want to stick to Github then you need to move to [HashBased location strategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy). It will simply solve your problem.
2. If you don't have any dependency on Github then you can move to other servers (firebase or apache) which support creating a htaccess file or any other fallback mechanism. ([See this link for more info](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)). This htaccess file is unfortunately not supported by Github yet. I personally prefer firebase due to these glitches.

By these fallback mechanisms I mean the server redirect to index.html i.e. your main HTML file in case of any 404 routes.

Comment: thank you ankit I now know the problem cause. I think this will continue to not-work on github. So I will move to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Either you use the locationHashStrategy you find here: https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

But then your URLs will have an additional # like: http://yourdomain.com/#/products

If you don't want that you have to add .htaccess and rewrite everything to index.html.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Save this as .htaccess in the same folder where your index.html is.

Comment: Downvoting. See this link: https://help.github.com/articles/redirects-on-github-pages/

Comment: Where in my answer is a link to github?

Comment: thank you @CarstenEnnulat for the explanation. Unfortunately github will not allow htaccess file.

Comment: Because you are telling them to add .htaccess file whereas github doesn't allow such file support.

Comment: @yogihosting okay, didn't know that, in that case you have to switch to hash locationstrategy

Comment: @AnkitKapoor sorry, didn't know that - but it's basically like the accepted answer, there is also reference to .htaccess, but why do I get the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a html file like below (src/404.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=app_path">
  <title>Redirecting...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>If you are not redirected, <a href="app_path">click here</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and in appRoutingModule use this - imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, **{ useHash: false })**],

then run a build command and check for 404 file inside you docs or root.
For me the above one is working