# Angular 4 routing not working on vps server

Tags: javascript, angular, .htaccess

After done the angular4 app "ng build --prod" and upload the production files to the "VPS server" then the angular app is running fine with routing. But whenever I reload some particular URL (e.g. example.io/register) and then I got the 404 page.

I have solved this type of issue on the apache server with .htaccess. Can anybody help me how to deploy app correctly or there any suitable .htaccess?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable on angular 4 but search about front controller, in your case it would be index.html and you may have to rewrite everything to this file.

Comment: Can you let me know the code how I rewrite everything to the index.html file? May I need some .htaccess configuration.

Answer (score -1):

This is the expected behaviour and you are handling it correctly as per [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples). Though you may want to look into these answers for some more info
1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428391/4632215
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47513836/4632215

Comment: I have checked your links, those are very useful but can you please let me know what I should do as my current position. Any solution or code?